# Refer to a subfolder of an installation path without repeating the name throughout the script

Tags: inno-setup, installation-path

When you give the folder location in the Inno Setup installer it sets it to the constant `{app}`. If the folder location is given as `C:\Program Files\Test1`, this will set it to `{app}` variable. When the user gives this path, is it possible to add to the `{app}` variable like this `C:\Program Files\Test1\MyApp-3.1`?

If the user gives the folder location as `C:\Program Files\Test1` and clicks the *Next* button then it should change it to `C:\Program Files\Test1\MyApp-3.1`. Is this possible?

According to [this page](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) `{app}` is a directory constant.

I have set many files to run in the following sections,

```
[Icons]
[Run]
[InstallDelete]
[UninstallRun]
```

For example, `{app}\Run.exe`. Instead of changing the `{app}\Run.exe` to `{app}\Program\Run.exe`, I need to change the `{app}` to `C:\Program Files\Test1\MyApp-3.1`.

I have a program which always needs to run from the folder structure `MyApp-3.1\Run.exe`. If the user select the installation folder as `C:\Program Files\Test1` then the folder needs to be set as `C:\Program Files\Test1\MyApp-3.1`. The easy way is to create the folder `MyApp-3.1` with the `Run.exe` in it and add that folder to the installer. So it will install the `MyApp-3.1` folder. The issue is if the folder name is change to `MyApp-3.2` then there have to be lot changes in the code.

The question is can you set the `{app}` variable after clicking the Next button in folder selection dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you actually need a [preprocessor macro](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define):

```
#define DestPath "{app}\MyApp-3.1"

[Files]
Source: "Run.exe"; DestDir: "{#DestPath}"
Source: "Otherfile"; DestDir: "{#DestPath}"

[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\My Program"; Filename: "{#DestPath}\Run.exe"; \
    WorkingDir: "{#DestPath}"

[Run]
Filename: "{#DestPath}\Run.exe"; Parameters: "/install"

[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{#DestPath}\Run.exe"; Parameters: "/uninstall"
```

If you need to change the subfolder name, just change the `DestPath` definition:

```
#define DestPath "{app}\MyApp-3.2"
```

Comment: Worked brilliant.